# Mysql. Deduct SUM(d.Amount) from SUM(c.Amount) and group by (depending on) values in other column

Tags: mysql

Here is MySQL table

```
Amount | DebitAccount | CreditAccount | TransactionPartnerName
--------------------------------------------------------------
 1     |     5610     |     5720      |    name one
 150   |     7210     |     5610      |    name one
```

Need to get something like this

```
name one result for account 5610 = 149.
((`CreditAccount` for `5610`) - (`DebitAccount` for `5610`)) = 149
```

In other words:

1) sum all `Amounts` where `DebitAccount` is `5610` and `TransactionPartnerName` is `name one`

2) sum all `Amounts` where `CreditAccount` is `5610` and `TransactionPartnerName` is `name one`

3) from `CreditAccount`sum deduct `DebitAccount`sum

Tried this code

```
SELECT TransactionPartnerName, SUM(Amount) 
FROM ( SELECT * FROM 2_1_journal) DATA 
WHERE (CAST(DebitAccount AS UNSIGNED) IN (?) OR CAST(CreditAccount AS UNSIGNED) IN (?)) 
GROUP BY TransactionPartnerName
```

But in result for account `5610` get value `151`. It means that `SUM(Amount)` of `DebitAccount` and `CreditAccount`.

Tried to think how to modify.

Tried something like this

```
SELECT TransactionPartnerName, 
IFNULL( d.Amount, 0 ) - IFNULL( c.Amount, 0 ) AS Amount 

FROM 

(
SELECT DebitAccount, 

SUM( Amount ) AS Amount FROM 
( SELECT * FROM 2_1_journal) DATA 

GROUP BY DebitAccount 
) d ON (AccountNumber = d.DebitAccount)

(
SELECT CreditAccount, 
SUM( Amount ) AS Amount FROM 
( SELECT * FROM 2_1_journal) DATA 
GROUP BY CreditAccount 
) c ON (AccountNumber = c.CreditAccount) 

GROUP BY TransactionPartnerName
```

but get blank page....

Please, advice what need to correct

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT TransactionPartnerName, SUM(if(CAST(DebitAccount AS UNSIGNED) IN (?), -Amount, Amount)) 
FROM 2_1_journal DATA 
WHERE (CAST(DebitAccount AS UNSIGNED) IN (?) OR CAST(CreditAccount AS UNSIGNED) IN (?)) 
GROUP BY TransactionPartnerName
```

Try this

Edit : Removed inner query

Comment: Unfortunately get blank page... no error message and no result

Comment: SELECT * FROM 2_1_journal where CAST(DebitAccount AS UNSIGNED) IN (?); Is this giving any result? Just to know whether your data is correct

Comment: Also does not give any result...But in question the code/query after words `Tried this code` is working....

Comment: Yes, there was problem with my data or `?`. Here are 3 `?` and I have only 2 elements for data. But at the moment not fully working as expected. Will experiment. When get working, will mark as accepted.